# Encontrar Id de la base de datos por medio de un input

Tags: javascript, mysql

Tengo un input en donde introduzco el id, lo que tiene que hacer es buscar si el id existe de la base de datos, por ejemplo, Id: 20, le doy click en el button para que verifique si exista el id y me tiene que mandar una alerta si no exista el id.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Es de mucha ayuda saber cómo lo estás implementado y agregar algo de código o captura de los errores.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que hacer una consulta SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM [tabla] WHERE id = :id
```

Puedo brindarte una descripcion mas detallada de los pasos si lo necesitas

Answer (score 0):

No es muy completa tu información; si es desde la base de datos puedes buscar de esta manera:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [tabla] WHERE id = idABuscar
```

En caso de no ser en la base de datos, debes crear un servicio para consultar a la base datos donde envíes el Id a buscar y retornes el resultado.

Si el resultado es nulo muestras la alerta informando lo sucedido.